# Single character ellipsis in monospace (teletype)

Tags: width, typewriter, ellipsis

I would like to get an ellipsis as a single (width) character in `\texttt`.
By default it uses three periods:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rcc}
    & ellipsis & three periods\\
    plain & \textellipsis & ...\\
    teletype & \texttt{\textellipsis} & \texttt{...}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled MWE]

I assume that the current behavior means I should not consider teletype (`\texttt`) as monospace, but as what one would do on a typewriter?

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own single-character-width ellipsis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\monoellipsis{\hbox to.5em{\hss.\hss\hss.\hss\hss.\hss}}
\begin{document}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rcc}
    & ellipsis & three periods & monoellipsis\\
    plain & \textellipsis & ... & \monoellipsis\\
    teletype & \texttt{\textellipsis} & \texttt{...} & \texttt{\monoellipsis}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a test for a monospaced font based on comparing the width of `i` and `m` in the current font. I use 0.5em because this is the usual width of glyphs in monospaced fonts. You might want to be on the safe side and use

```
\fontcharwd\font`x
```

instead of `0.5em` and `` 0.33333\fontcharwd\font`x `` instead of `0.16667em`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\kerneltextellipsis\textellipsis
\newcommand{\textmonoellipsis}{%
  \makebox[0.5em]{%
    \makebox[0.16667em]{.}\hfil
    \makebox[0.16667em]{.}\hfil
    \makebox[0.16667em]{.}%
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\textellipsis{%
  \ifdim\fontcharwd\font`i=\fontcharwd\font`m
    % i and m have equal width: monospaced font
    \textmonoellipsis
  \else
    \kerneltextellipsis
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

Normal text\dots

\texttt{Mono text\dots xyz}

\texttt{Mono textXxyz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `\dots` the same as `\textellipsis` in text mode?

Comment: @equaeghe Yes: `\dots` actually does `\ifmmode\mathellipsis\else\textellipsis\fi`